# PHPUnit: What does syntaxCheck configuration parameter stands for exactly

Tags: php, unit-testing, configuration, phpunit

I can't find it in documentation nor on google search which is strange.

What does `syntaxCheck` configuration parameter stands for exactly in PHPUnit configuration XML file?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That configuration setting has not had an effect in years. It was removed long ago.

Comment: But what the fork does it do? I'm trying to refactor an existing app and I need to know what it did.

Comment: Still haven't found an answer to this. I guess it is lost to time, unless Mr. Bergmann tells us or something ;-)

Comment: I just discovered the same issue today on PHPUnit 8.*  my tests seem to pass but the error message is worrying